# Update database entry with time field closest to now()

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL database table with the structure described below.

```
uid         info           time
6           null           2013-04-12 23:00:00
5           something      2013-04-12 22:00:00
4           something      2013-04-10 09:00:00
3           something      2013-04-09 19:00:00
2           something      2013-04-02 10:00:00
1           something      2013-04-01 11:00:00
```

How is it posible to update the row with the lastest time value in one single MySQL query?

One of the possible solutions is

```
SELECT uid FROM my_table ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
UPDATE my_table SET info = 'something' WHERE uid = 'uid_received_in_previuos_query'
```

But it is two sequential queries solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what I was searching for

```
 UPDATE my_table SET info = 'something' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you're looking for the [MySQL NOW() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

Usage example:

```
UPDATE my_table SET info='something', time=NOW() WHERE id=6
```

Or, if you're looking for the latest row to udpate with anything, you could

```
UPDATE my_table SET info='something', time=NOW() ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @zavg Edited. How about now? :)

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't work. I posted the answer I found among others.

Comment: @zavg There ya go (edited second query). I tried it and it works. You might need to carefully choose the type of the `time` column for the proper granularity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below

```
WHERE time > '2013-04-12 00:00:01' and time < '2013-04-12 23:59:59'
```

**For Dynamic Date**

```
WHERE time > date ("Y-m-d").'00:00:01' and time < date ("Y-m-d").'23:59:59'
```

Comment: I need to update row with the latest value in time field. I don't now exactly this value.

Comment: Look at my post updates, I think that you misunderstood me a little

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
update  tableName first  inner join (SELECT uid FROM tableName ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1) as second SET first.info = 'something' where first.uid = second.uid
```